# How to join 2 stack navigators in React Native

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

I have 2 stack navigators that handles 2 diferrent slices of my app, one will be the authentication and the other will be the app itself. I would like to put these 2 stack navigators in different files and one file to join both. Is there a way to do this?

MainNavigation code

```
import React from 'react'
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native'

import AuthNav from './AuthNav'
import AppNav from './AppNav'

const MainNav = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <AuthNav />
            <AppNav />
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}

export default MainNav
```

AppNavigation code

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator<AppNavParams>()
const AppNav = () => {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Register">
                {props => <RegisterScreen {...props} />}
            </Stack.Screen>
        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}
```

AuthNavigation Code

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator<AppNavParams>()
const AuthNav = () => {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Login">
                {props => <RegisterScreen {...props} />}
            </Stack.Screen>
        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}
```

edit1: removed image and inserted code

Comment: Can you put the code in the question as text instead of image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an `auth` stack and `user` stack and render based on `sign` state.

1. Create your auth stack.

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function AuthStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

2. Create your user stack.

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function UserStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="User" component={UserScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

3. Render `auth` or `user` based on `sign` state.

```
export default function Account({ navigation, route }) {
  const [sign, setSign] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // some logic to check user sign
  }, []);

  if (sign) {
    return <UserStack />;
  } else {
    return <AuthStack />;
  }
}
```

4. Wrap with navigation container

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Account/>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to verify if your authenticated token exist or not, in your `MainNav`
And create a stack navigator around both `AppNav` and `AuthNav`

You can do something like this

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer, useLinking } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'

import AppNav from './AppNav'
import AuthNav from './AuthNav'

const AppStack = createStackNavigator()

const MainNav() => {

  const someFn = () => {
    // write your logic here. Either retrieve from redux store or from local storage
    // return true or false
  }

  const isLoggedIn = someFn()


  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AppStack.Navigator>
        {isLoggedIn ? (
          <AppStack.Screen name='App' component={AppNav} />
        ) : (
          <AppStack.Screen name='Auth' component={AuthNav} />
        )}
      </AppStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```